# How to persist redux data in react native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I’ve been struggling on this problem for while n now it’s a pretty simple issue I need a way to persist my data from redux into react native’s local storage I have tried using multiple approaches like the redux-persist library but I still have not been able to crack it… has anyone found a solution to this issue, I’m open to all approaches.

Here is the code I used for the redux-persist library

`store.ts`

```js
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {persistStore} from 'redux-persist';

import authReducer from './reducers/authReducer';
import toastReducer from './reducers/toastReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  toast: toastReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
});

export const Store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export const PersistedStore = persistStore(Store);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof Store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof Store.dispatch;
```

`authReducer.ts`

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';

import {AuthResponse} from '../../types/AuthResponse';
import {AuthReduxAction} from '../../types/ReduxActions';
import {SET_USER_DETAILS} from '../constants';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

interface State {
  userDetails: AuthResponse;
}

const initialState: State = {
  userDetails: {},
};

const authReducer: (
  state: State,
  action: AuthReduxAction,
) => State | Promise<State> = async (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER_DETAILS:
      // Saving user details to local storage
      return {...state, userDetails: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer);
```

`App.tsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import Routes from './Routes';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import {LogBox} from 'react-native';

import {PersistedStore, Store} from './redux/store';

LogBox.ignoreLogs(['new NativeEventEmitter']);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={PersistedStore}>
        <Routes />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is the response I get when I print out the data (auth data in this case) from the redux store:
`{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null, "_persist": {"rehydrated": true, "version": -1}}`

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: "I have tried using multiple approaches like the redux-persist library but I still have not been able to crack it" - **show us your code** that uses `redux-persist` then. How else can we help you? We aren't psychic.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The data does not get persisted, when I restart my app and print out the data from redux, the response does not include the data I inserted, furthermore I do not know if I should use my `persistReducer` method on each individual reducer or my rootReducer in which I use my `combineReducer` method....

Comment: You should not be using any persistence code in your reducers: that's IO, and reducers should be _pure functions_ with no side-effects (that especially includes IO). Instead have an action that invokes the persistence lib and have that action triggered whenever is appropriate (which is _not_ every time your Redux state is mutated, because Redux state includes ephemeral state and other insignificant changes that do no need to be persisted).

Comment: I do not think there is a way to programmatically save the state in local storage using this library as it gives also zero customization on how you can use it, I can save my state manually into local storage, but can you provide a code snippet that loads the state from local storage into redux store and then loads the entire app, as I need all the data on app start this is what the `PersistGate` component achieves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to do redux-persist this way and it works for several projects. Check it out if it works for you.

store.js

```js
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import thunkMiddleware from "redux-thunk";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import reducer from "./reducers/";

const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        createLogger({
            collapsed: true,
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
            predicate: () => __DEV__,
        })
    ),
];

/* eslint-disable no-undef */
const composeEnhancers =
    (__DEV__ &&
        typeof window !== "undefined" &&
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
    compose;
/* eslint-enable no-undef */

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(...enhancers);

const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    blacklist: [],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducer);
export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, {}, enhancer);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

authReducer.js

```js
import {AuthResponse} from '../../types/AuthResponse';
import {AuthReduxAction} from '../../types/ReduxActions';
import {SET_USER_DETAILS} from '../constants';


interface State {
  userDetails: AuthResponse;
}

const initialState: State = {
  userDetails: {},
};

const authReducer: (
  state: State,
  action: AuthReduxAction,
) => State | Promise<State> = async (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER_DETAILS:
      // Saving user details to local storage
      return {...state, userDetails: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default authReducer;
```

index.js (same location as authReducer.js)

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import authReducer from './authReducer';
import toastReducer from './toastReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    authReducer ,
    toastReducer
});
```